# PHP/SQL - How can I get the name of tables in my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use the function `mysqli_fetch_field()` to get the name of each of my tables in the database. However when i try to output the table name using `$fieldInfo->table` i get duplicates. How can i select only 1 column from each table so that `$fieldInfo->table` isnt called for every column of each table?

current sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from administrators, bookings, customers, rooms";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error($conn));
```

my code to display the table name in radio buttons:

```
<?php
while ($fieldInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($results)) { 
?>
<input type="radio" name="tableNames" value="<?php echo $fieldInfo->table; ?>"> <?php echo $fieldInfo->table ?> <br>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `resource mysql_list_tables ( string $database [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`, [function.mysql-list-tables.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php)

Comment: @FrayneKonok There is a difference between `mysqli` and `mysql`...

Comment: What about `SELECT 1 from administrators, bookings, customers, rooms`?

Comment: I think this will help the OP. [displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898610/displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 temporary table name holder and made an IF condition that only outputs the radio buttons once the 2 temporary name holders are different.

```
<?php
    $tempName2 = "";
    while ($fieldInfo = mysqli_fetch_field($results)) { 
        $tempName = $fieldInfo->table;
        if ($tempName != $tempName2) {
            $tempName2 = $tempName;
?>
    <input type="radio" name="tableNames" value="<?php echo $tempName; ?>" > <?php echo $tempName ?> <br>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query='SHOW TABLES FROM DB_NAME';
$results=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($fieldInfo = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { ?>
    <input type="radio" name="tableNames" value="<?php echo $fieldInfo[0]; ?>"> <?php echo $fieldInfo[0]; ?> <br>
<?php } ?>
```