# I have a php error. But I don't understand why

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in my code. I'm trying to make a private chat. I am using php and mysql. But now I have this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Table 'b7_19757973_4hfbroup.asdfannedegraaff' doesn't exist" And I know that it means that the table does not exist. But I use this code to look if the table exist:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `".$_SESSION['senderreceiver']."`");
if(!$query)
   echo "The s does not exists";
$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `".$_SESSION['receiversender']."`");
if(!$query2)
   echo "The f does not exists";
```

But I still get the error, How can I fix this?

btw the session are made like this:

```
$sender = $_SESSION['username']; 
$receiver = $_POST["name"];
$senderreceiver = $sender . $receiver;
$receiversender = $receiver . $sender;

$_SESSION['senderreceiver'] = $senderreceiver;
$_SESSION['receiversender'] = $receiversender;
```

I'm sorry for my bad english and for my bad explanation. But I hope you can help me..

Comment: Well, does that table exist? Or, more likely, do you have a period in your column name?

Comment: @JohnConde No that table does not exist. But I want that it seeks for the right one, because one of them exists.

Comment: `if(){}else{}` its what u need.... are u sure your table name is stored in a session?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I tried if(){}else{} but then I got the same error, then I tried this, and it still does not work. I still got that error

Comment: but why are u storing table in a session?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I made a system that if you open this page it makes a database's table(from the name of the maker and the receiver) and there I want to store the messages. But that is on a other page. Thats why I use session. I want if someone else tries to open the private chat that it searches for both of the possible tables and then opens the right one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898610/displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database

Comment: Terrible idea. Don't dynamically create tables on the fly. There's no need for that at all.

Comment: What should i do instead?

Comment: Use one predefined table in which you store all your messages. What problem are you trying to solve by splitting those across different tables?

Comment: @deceze Oh nice idea, never thought about that *facepalm*

Comment: [*giant facepalm*](https://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/3657230_700b.jpg)

Comment: @deceze btw, Is there a possibilitie for something like: `$test = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from msg_private WHERE sender='$username' OR sender='$receiver' ");` ?

Comment: @AnneDeGraaff Uhm… yes!? Not sure what you're unsure about.

Comment: @deceze It does not work thats why, but do you have a link that explains how it works. Or can you explain me how I could get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Table does not exist, MYSQLI will ALWAYS throw that Error.

Try instead `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tablename';`

But one further concern: Do not save Database table names inside the Session. It's bad practice and in 99% of the cases not needed

Comment: And if the table does not exist?

Comment: **MYSQLI will ALWAYS throw that Error.**

Comment: The Resultset will either have a result or not, so just check what the return holds

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @Ann-SophieAngermüller btw, Is there a possibilitie for something like: `$test = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from msg_private WHERE sender='$username' OR sender='$receiver' ");` ?

Comment: Give it a try ;) If you use phpmyadmin to administrate your MySQL you can fire queries there to see if an "OR" works in this case or not