# showing my database tables using selection in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i'm trying to display all my tables in database with this code.

```
<label>
  <select class="selectpicker" name="tabel">

        <?php
        include "koneksi.php";
        $koneksi ->select_db('testskripsi');
        $sql =  mysqli_query($koneksi, "show tables") ;
        while($table = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<option name="opsi" value = "' . $table['Tables'] . '">' . $table['Tables'] . '</option>';
        }

        ?>
    </select>
</label>
```

here's my result

[image]

i think i don't know how to fill this array to make my tables displayed

```
' . $table['Tables'] . '
```

Comment: Change `$table['Tables'] ` to `$table['Tables_in_databasename'] `<< write your database name in place of `databasename`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898610/displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database

Comment: The Follow link will be Useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898610/displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database

Comment: In general you can use `var_dump()` function to inspect complex variables. Here `var_dump($table)` within the `while` loop.

Comment: @Cavin Anil already spotted the duplicate

Comment: The SO link posted here is **not** a duplicate since there is no attempt to read the field `Tables` instead of `Tables_in_<databasename>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try Tables_in_testskripsi instead of Tables.here is the correct code of yours.

```
<label>
<select class="selectpicker" name="tabel">

    <?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $koneksi ->select_db('testskripsi');
    $sql =  mysqli_query($koneksi, "show tables") ;
    while($table = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<option name="opsi" value = "' . $table['Tables_in_testskripsi'] . '">' . $table['Tables_in_testskripsi'] . '</option>';
    }

    ?>
</select>
</label>
```

do let me know if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

To get table names,

```
$tables=$this->db->query("
  SELECT t.TABLE_NAME AS myTables
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
  WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database name'
  AND t.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%a%' 
")->result_array();

foreach($tables as $key => $val) {
  echo $val['myTables']."<br>";// myTables is the alias used in query.
}
```

Comment: Just indent each line of code with 4 spaces to get a code box with syntax highlighting. I've fixed it up and included some linebreaks to get it more readable.