# Extract a phpmyadmin table name using react

Tags: reactjs, phpmyadmin

ello,

I created a CRUD application based on mysql database and react as framework,
As i’m going to use multiple tables in the database, I want to create a first page that extracts from the database all the tables names on a list. Once the list with the tables names is created, i want to be able to click on the table name and be redirected to the CRUD page that I already created.
The code below is what I used to create the first page but it failed to work.
I attached phpmyadmin database and the capture of structure of the project

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

   const TabList = () => {
   const [tab, settab] = useState("");
  
   useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php? 
    route=/database/structure&server=1&db=crud_db')
      .then(res=>{
      console.log(res)
      settab(res.data)
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="columns mt-5 is-centered">
    <div className="column is-half">
      <table className="table is-striped is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>N</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {tab.map((tab , index) => (
            <tr key={tab.id}>
              <td>{index + 1}</td>
              <td>{tab.name}</td>
               
             
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
};
export default TabList;
```

[tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3sEi.png)

[vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIZga.png)

[vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jrYf.png)

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898610/displaying-all-table-names-in-php-from-mysql-database

Comment: @JackLarson thank you but this is using php. How can i convert it to javascript